# Calculating the cubic root for negative number

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to calculate the real answer of the cubic root of a **negative** number using C#. `Math.Pow(-2, (1.0/3.0))` results in `NaN`. How do I calculate the real answer in C#?

*Some posts on StackOverflow already addressed how to calculate the cubic or n<sup>th</sup> root of a number. But none of them how to calculate this on a negative number, which results in complex numbers.*

I'm trying to port an Excel sheet to C#. In Excel `=POWER(-2;1/3)` returns a real number.

According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1432963/excel-power-function-fractional-power-issue), the cubic root of a negative base has a real number answer, and two complex number answers.

I'm not interested in mathematically most correct solution, but having the ported C# code behave exactly the same as the Excel's `=POWER()` function, which returns the real number answer.

Comment: You can use an interop call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another way to calculate cube root in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817740/another-way-to-calculate-cube-root-in-c-sharp)

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [Find Cube root of a number Using System.Math.Pow() method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25743901/995714), [C# math.pow cube root calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38942580/995714)

Comment: First `1.0/3.0` is rounded because it can not be represented exactly so you are losing precision even before you start computing.  To remedy that see [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) on how to compute that on your own.  Second the result of `(-2)^(1.0/3.0)` is not real number that is why `NaN` is returned. I do not know how your EXCEL is doing this so probably `pow(fabs(-2),(1.0/3.0))` or `|pow(-2,(1.0/3.0))|` which is on complex domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write your own function that does something like this:

```
private static double CubeRoot(double x) {
    if (x < 0)
        return -Math.Pow(-x, 1d / 3d);
    else
        return Math.Pow(x, 1d / 3d);
}
```

Comment: why on earth do you use float in a double function? It's far less precise than `1.0/3.0`

Comment: Indeed, 1d/3d would be better, oops.  Updated my answer to use double-precision floating point.

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.Cbrt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cbrt?view=netcore-2.1) was introduced in .NET Core/Standard 2.1 to calculate cube root. Now you can get both **mathematically correct** and **more precise** result than before

Just call `Math.Cbrt(-2)`